# how do i modify jquery sms counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using an sms counter to show remaining number of character and number of sms, but i want to do a bit modification on this, what i want is to change max remaining character from 160 to 145 when sms > 1

here is my code which always counts 160 characters.

```
<textarea name="message" value="" id="message"></textarea>
<p>
<span id="remaining">160 characters remaining</span>
<span id="messages">1 message(s)</span>
</p>

document).ready(function(){
    var $remaining = $('#remaining'),
    $messages = $remaining.next();

    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        var chars = this.value.length,
        messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160),
        remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);

       $remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
       $messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
   });
});
```

Comment: so right now you have done nothing to change remaining char to 145 ?

Comment: i have tried  if(messages>1){
remaining = messages * 145 - (chars % (messages * 145) || messages * 145);
}

Comment: by this code it will take 145 chars for first msg too

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the below code

```
if(messages>1)
    { 



    remaining = (((messages-1) * 145)+160 - chars ); 


    }
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfanneht/1/)

Comment: after reach the limit 160 for message 1 it shows  -144/ 2 and the renaining character increases negatively such as -202/2

Comment: i have edited the code 1 min ago.. did you check that ?

Comment: yes, i checked it right now, here is another problem!!  sms remaining char again increase negatively after message 2 and message no doesn't increase to message 3 -4/ 2

Comment: and since you are not calculating the `chars` value properly ,, you are getting wrong `messages` variable value.... so nothing wrong with my code

Comment: i checked jsfiddle several times, it also shows same problem i mentioned above. after completing message 2 message no doesn't change and remaining char increases negatively.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101847/discussion-between-user-4653387-and-yo-yo).

Comment: and i told you where the problem is .. you are not calculating the `messages` value properly .... you should calculate the `messages` correctly and than my code will work perfectly .....

Answer (score 1):

This will work, I tested it....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $remaining = $('#remaining'),
$messages = $remaining.next();

$('#message').keyup(function(){
    var chars = this.value.length; 
    if(chars <= 305){
    var messages = Math.ceil(chars / 145);
    var remaining = messages * 145 - (chars % (messages * 145) || messages * 145); 
    }       
    else if(chars <= 160){
    var messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160);
    var remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);
    }
    else{ 
    var messages = Math.ceil(chars / 145);
    var remaining = messages * 145 - (chars % (messages * 145) || messages * 145); 
    }
   $remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
   $messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
});
});
```

Comment: when i remove the characters pressing backspace it always stucks in 144!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that.
Use this one I coded it for you.
This code is more accurate than last one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $remaining = $('#remaining'),
$messages = $remaining.next();
var arr = [0, 160, 305, 450, 595, 740, 885, 1030, 1175, 1320, 1465, 1610, 1755, 1900];
$('#message').keyup(function(){
var chars = this.value.length;          
for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(chars >=arr[i]){
        $messages.text((i+1) + ' message(s)');          
        $remaining.text((arr[(i+1)]-chars) + ' characters remaining');
    }
}
});
});
```